# Nginx: How to add headers to only specific files and text

Tags: nginx

I have multiple urls that needs to add same sets of header with nginx. Here is the file names.

```
File Group1
    https://www.example.com/news/2017-08-03/article-xyz/
    https://www.example.com/news/2017-08-03/article-xyz/topics/
    https://www.example.com/news/2017-08-03/article-xyz/gallery/

File Group2
    https://www.example.com/news/2017-08-02/article-abc/
    https://www.example.com/news/2017-08-02/article-abc/topics/
    https://www.example.com/news/2017-08-02/article-abc/gallery/
```

So in this case File Group1 needs:

```
add_header Cache-Tag  article-xyz;
```

And File Group2 needs:

```
add_header Cache-Tag  article-abc;
```

So nginx.conf should be something like this

```
  location /news/ {
        add_header Cache-Tag  article-abc;
    }
```

But how can I apply this dynamically in add headers?

Answer (score 5):

One solution is to use a `map` directive on the `$request_uri` value. For example:

```
map $request_uri $cache_tag {
    default        "";
    ~/article-xyz/ "article-xyz";
    ~/article-abc/ "article-abc";
}
server {
    ...
    add_header Cache-Tag $cache_tag;
    ...
}
```

The `map` block lives outside the `server` block (as shown). The `add_header` statement can be in the `server` scope or in the `location` block which finally processes the request (subject to inheritance rules). See [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) and [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header) for details.

Do not use captures in the `map` directive, as it will not work.

Comment: What happens when directory name is unique like ~/article-XXX/ or ~/name-of-article/